# How to download gitorious.org file?

Tags: git, gitorious

i wanna download files from gitorious.org (https://gitorious.org/sitara-bootcamp/meta-custom) 
I use git clone command and get the following error message...
Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

```
sitara@ubuntu:~/tisdk/sources$ git clone git://gitorious.org/sitara-bootcamp/meta-custom.git -b amsdk-06.00.00.00
Cloning into 'meta-custom'...
fatal: unable to connect to gitorious.org:
gitorious.org[0: 64.13.172.37]: errno=Connection refused
gitorious.org[1: 2a02:c0:1014::1]: errno=Network is unreachable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gitorious doesn't seem to expose this repo via the `git://` protocol, but you can download it via HTTP:

```
mureinik@computer ~/src/git $ git clone http://gitorious.org/sitara-bootcamp/meta-custom.git -b amsdk-06.00.00.00
Cloning into 'meta-custom'...
remote: Counting objects: 70, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (57/57), done.
remote: Total 70 (delta 21), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (70/70), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
```